# Do some Pokemon learn new moves through generations?

Tags: pokemon-series

I want to know if some Pokemon that can't learn a move in a previous generation can learn it when transferred to a newer generation/game.

Does this exist?

Answer (score 7):

There are some old pokemon that learn new attacks, notably due to the introduction of new attacks (new mechanics like day/night, weather or through an entirely new type: Steel or Fairy). But it's also possible that some already existed attacks were added to the move-set of an already existed Pokemon.

Here is a little example:

- **Gyarados** is a 1st generation Pokemon, but he can learn **Thrash** only since 2nd generation (and **Thrash** already existed in 1st generation, **Nidoking** is the best example for this attack) -> **Tauros** is in the same case too

Comment: So if i transfer a pokemon which was caught in the 1st generation to Sun/Moon it can learn all the moves added in his moveset in the later games

Comment: yeah, but he won't be able to return to the 1rst generation

Comment: Nice find. I knew it was possible like this, just couldn't think of any examples :)

Comment: @Mathias711 I could had take evolution example too (eevee, electabuzz), because they learn new moves due to their new evolutions

Comment: There's some examples from new moves within the generations as well. In Generation 1, Charizard cannot learn Fly in Red/Blue, but **can** learn it in Yellow. Thus, it is possible to trade Charizard from say Red to Yellow, teach it Fly, and trade it back to Red.

Comment: @Robotnik I didn't know that workaround